Rails Gems that use JS not loading when navigating with Turbo in Production
I have a Rails 7 app using Turbo and ESBuild.
Some of my Gems (Recaptcha, Chartkick etc) also have a JS component. While on my localhost everything works fine, after uploading to Heroku the charts and recaptchas do not load when navigating to a page using Turbo. When doing a full page reload everything works but with Turbo they don't load, and are showing no error as well.
Since on localhost everything works and in production no errors (not in the console nor in the server log) are shown it's difficult to debug.
Any ideas?

This issue ticket might help: https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/issues/407
